# How to draw boolean columns with another column as hue?

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, boolean, seaborn

I'm facing a bit of a problem here.
I have a dataset of this kind:

```
ID       Boolean1      Boolean2     Class
1        True          True         1-5
2        True          False        10-15
3        False         False        10-15
4        True          False        5-10
5        False         True         1-5
```

I would like to get a barplot with the frequency of those having Boolean1 == True, those having Boolean2 == True, those having both Boolean1 and Boolean2 == True and those having both == False. All this frequency should have "Class" as hue.

That would result in a barplot with 4 "main" bars, each one divided in 3 depending on the class (1-5, 5-10 or 10-15).

I have no idea how to proceed. Is someone able to help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `crosstab` here:

```
pd.crosstab([df['Boolean1'], df['Boolean2']], df['Class']).plot.bar()
```

would give you:

[image]

Or you can swap the arguments in `crosstab`:

```
pd.crosstab(df['Class'], [df['Boolean1'], df['Boolean2']]).plot.bar()
```

and you get

[image]